# Is there a way to filter-out the last item in an Excel PivotTable field using the context menu filter when grand totals are not visible in the table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

In a pivot table,  you can right-click an item in a field, choose "Filter">"Hide Selected items" and that specific item, or selected items, will be filtered out of the view.

I find this very useful, but recently I've come across a situation where it doesn't work.

If I have a pivot table with no column grand total, and I try to filter out the last item in the field from the rows, I get the message "You cannot hide this selection". For example, if I do this:

[image]

I get this message:
[image]

If I add the column grand total to the pivot table, I can filter the item away without a problem.

The same situation happens when trying to remove the last item from a column field which has no row grand totals.

**My question is: is there a way to avoid this behavior?**

In my example, I used this query to get the data on country population from Wikipedia:

```
let
    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_and_dependencies_by_population")),
    Data0 = Source{0}[Data],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data0,{{"Rank", type text}, {"Country (or dependent territory)", type text}, {"Population", type text}, {"% of world population", type text}, {"Date", type text}, {"Source", type text}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each [Rank] <> "Rank"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Filtered Rows",{{"Population", Int64.Type}, {"% of world population", Percentage.Type}, {"Date", type date}, {"Rank", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

I created a pivot table and put "Country (or dependent territory)" on Rows and "Sum of Population" in Values.

In case it matters, I have these default settings for pivot tables (under Options>Data>Edit Default Layout):

[image]

I've googled for this particular situation but my efforts are coming up short.

I am using Excel for Office 365 MSO (16.0.12527.20260).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable selection to be able to hide the item from the context-menu.

1. Select the cell (or row) of the item you want to hide.
2. On the PivotTable Analyze tab, on the Actions group, select "Select"

[image: IMG:]

3. Then choose the option "Enable Selection". The row will be selected automatically not just the cell in step 1. if the row is not selected, repeat step 2. If you had already selected the row during step 1, if after clicking on "Enable Selection", the row is no longer selected, then click one more time on "Enable Selection".

[image: IMG:]

4. Now you can from the context-menu click on Filter -> "Hide Selected Items".

Comment: Well, that works! But I still think there's something wonky with Excel in this behavior.

I can filter-out any item in the field other than the last item without enabling selection first. And if I add the grand total, I can filter out the last item as well. 

Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Owen True, it is an odd behavior. You can even filter it out from when drilling down item from the column, but when doing it from the context-menu without enabling selection, you get that error message.